# mysql join(one to many) aggregate function duplicates rows count

Tags: mysql, join

I have got three table

**book**
book_id
outstanding_amt
created_date

**log**
log_id
book_id
paid_id
event_name (3 types of events)

**paid**
paid_id
amt_paid

relation between book book and log is one to many. and relation between log and paid one to one.

I want to join these three tables and get data grouped by events with its outstanding_amt.

for eg. 
event_name   outstanding_amt  amt_paid

The query i am using right now is duplicating outstanding amount.

```
select event_name, sum(outstanding_amt), sum(amt_paid)
from log
inner join book on book.book_id = log.book_id
inner join paid on log.paid_id = paid.paid_id
group by month(created_date);
```

since for one row in book, there is multiple rows in log, when i write sum(outstanding_amt), since join is executed before aggregation, these two tables are joined, and after that sum is applied, so sums up duplicate rows that is found in event_log. And it shows much higher amt it actually is.

I have to display data on month basis, when book was created i.e.created_date

Comment: Try to group the  result

Comment: If the relationship is one to one, why bother with a separate table? Perhaps this schema design requires more thought.

Comment: relationship is one to many between book and log table

Answer (score 0):

You can archive this using `group by`

```
select book.book_id, event_name, sum(outstanding_amt), sum(amt_paid)
from log
inner join book on book.book_id = log.book_id
inner join paid on log.paid_id = paid.paid_id GROUP BY book.book_id
```

Comment: i dont have to group by book_id, i have to group by month of book created_date as per my requirement